# Restws module exposing custom module content

Tags: hooks

I'm using [RESTws module](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws) and access content via /node/id.json. I've written a custom module and use the "hook_entity_property_info" which exposes these fields:

```
{
  "entity_id": 6655,
  "cloudinary": {
    "publicID": "sdfg334fsdsdfv",
    "title": "test title",
    "caption": "test caption",
    "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/cloudname/image/upload/asdfd",
    "credit": "© test",
    "keywords": "",
    "description": "sdfgdfsg",
    "primaryImage": "0"
    "width": "300"
    "height": "100"
    "ratio": "1.6"
    "crop": "{'height':100,'width':100,'ratio':1.6}"
  }
}
```

This works for a node (I can see all my fields). When I use a field collection the module field is completely missing:

```
{
    "field_answer_v": "test test test",
    "field_correct_v": false,
    "field_feedback_v": null,
    "item_id": "345",
    "revision_id": "345",
    "field_name": "field_answer_fc",
    "url": "http://url/cms/field-collection/field-answer-fc/13085",
    "host_entity": 
    {
        "uri": "http://url/cms/node/3067",
        "id": "3067",
        "resource": "node"
    }
}
```

When I use "hook_field_collection_item_load", and print the value out in PHP, the module field is there!

```
"field_cloudinary": {
    "und":[ {
                "publicID":"asdfasdf",
                "title":"test",
                "caption":"",
                "url":"http:\/\/url\/image\/upload\/asdfds.jpg",
                "credit":"\u00a9 ",
                "keywords":"",
                "description":"test",
                "primaryImage":"0",
                "height":"1355",
                "width":"2048",
                "ratio":"0.661621",
                "crop":""
        } ]
},
```

The data is there but why is it not appearing in the restws module? Is there some other hook I need to use? This is causing some major headaches :-p

Comment: I believe field collections consist of multiple entities. So you fetch the field collection, and you will be presented with more url's to fetch for each of the fields.

Comment: Have you tried fetching http://url/cms/field-collection/field-answer-fc/13085 ? I am pretty sure they are there.

Comment: That's strange. It's been a while since I used restws, but as I remember it, the field collection appeared on the node and then there were more url's to fetch for each of the fields in the collection. But I can't verify that now. Perhaps it gets you somewhere...

Comment: @Neograph734 I just updated again. When I use hook_field_collection_item_load and echo the content the cloudinary field is there! but it disappears by the time it gets through to restws

Comment: Got this from the RestWs issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/node/1609328. You should be able to construct an url to fetch the data (apparently there is no way to set it).